# Give me both of them. / Give me both. / Give me them both. / Give me both ones

Tags: pronouns

As I understand it, all answers are correct but the last one is rare. So, all versions are interchangeable, aren't they?

> 'Would you like to have this ice-cream or that?'
>
> **Give me both of them. / Give me both. / Give me them both. / Give me both ones.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Both ones" is less likely to be used. If you had two coins of €1 and a €10 bill, it might make sense, meaning just the two *single* Euro coins, i.e., "ones," in colloquial English, but that phrase is unlikely in *adult* conversation.

That said, all the other choices are equivalent, with no difference in meaning.